# For Loops and Characters

Tags: java

I'm learning for loops and am having a hard time understanding how to print these characters out

```
@@..XXXXXXXXX
@@@@..XXXXXXX
@@@@@@..XXXXX
@@@@@@@@..XXX
```

Here is my attempt:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 12; j > 10-i; j-=2)
    {
         System.out.print("@");
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < i-2; j++){
        System.out.print("..");
    }
    for(int j =9; j < i; j-=3){
        System.out.print("X");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

so the `@` adds two every time.
`..` stays at two.
`X` adds 3.
Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: what are you allowed to use ?, is there other requirements than using loops ?

Comment: Create one loop that iterates 4 times, calculate the required number of each character on each iteration. Btw, for X, two are removed on very iteration, so if you would loop from 1 to 4: `@ = i * 2`, `. = 2` and `X = 11 - (i * 2)`.

Comment: no it should al be in a for loops using nested loops @Mikenno

Comment: @Luis what do you mean when you say your X adds 3 but in your post X decrement by 2?

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out the pattern of `@`, `.` and `X`. There are total 4 lines. Let's say from line 0 to line 3. For each line `i`.

1. number of `@`: 2, 4, 6, 8  → `2i+2`
2. number of `.`: 2, 2, 2, 2  → `2`
3. number of `X`: 9, 7, 5, 3  → `-2i+9`

So the code should follow the pattern we discovered.

```
for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<2*i+2;  ++j) System.out.print("@");
    for (int j=0; j<2;      ++j) System.out.print(".");
    for (int j=0; j<-2*i+9; ++j) System.out.print("X");
    System.out.println();
}
```

So, before you start coding. Make sure you know what you are going to do, find out the pattern of the problem you are solving, check the algorithm you are going to implement.

Comment: Thank you @delta that makes sense now that I saw how you wrote it. I will do that, I think I just ahead before I even knew! Thanks Again

Comment: great coding mate its very neat

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it is easier if you split it out to different method

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        printPattern1 (x + 1);
        printPattern2 (x);
    }

}

private static void printPattern1(int x) {

    while (x-- > 0) {
        System.out.print("@@");
    }
    System.out.print("..");

}
private static void printPattern2(int x) {

    for (int y=0; y < (-2 * x+9); y++){
        System.out.print("X");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I understand to your question:

//Input: n=12  ---- so that we can have, for the last sequence, 10 '@' consecutively

```
    public class ForLoop {
        public static void main(String []args) {
            int n = 12;
            for(int i = 2; i < n; i+=2){
                for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    System.out.print("@");
                }
                System.out.print("..");
                for(int k = n; k > i + 1; k--){
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
           }
        }
    }
```